# Board not updating position in python. The variable resets itself

Tags: python, loops, variables

I have the following code in file a:

```
while(won == False):
    game.userY = setGameRow(row, counter)
    game.userX = setGameCol(col, counter)
    counter+=1
    printBoard(bd, game.userX , game.userY)
    move(row, col, bd, mines, game.userX, game.userY)
    won = retWon()
```

And in file b:

```
def move(row, col, bd, mines, userX, userY):
    i = inp()
    if(i == "w"):
        movX = 0
        movY = -1
    elif(i == "a"):
        movX = -1
        movY = 0
    elif(i == "s"):
        movX = 0
        movY = 1
    elif(i == "d"):
        movX = 1
        movY = 0

    if((userY == 0 and inp == "w") or (userY == col-1 and inp == "s") or (userX == 0 and inp == "a") or (userX == row-1 and inp == "d")):
        print("Invalid movement")
        move(row, col, bd, mines)

    userX += movX
    userY += movY
    

    if(getNumbers(userX, userY, bd) == 9):
        lost(mines, row, col)
    if(userX==0 and userY == 0):
        win(mines, row, col)
```

The board looks like this:

```
Where do you want to go? w
+----------+
|··········|
|··········|
|··········|
|··········|
|··········|
|··········|
|··········|
|··········|
|········00|
|········0*|
+----------+
```

The player is `·`

userX and userY change again to their defualt value when `printBoard()` is executed. I know that they do change but they always end up changing back to their default value so the board doesn't update when I move the player.

Comment: as we cannot see your full code, it is difficult to say how you are passing along the attributes between functions. My guess from your code snippet is that userX and userY is only locally updated inside your move function, and not globally updated throughout your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
userX += movX
userY += movY
```

in the `move()` function, you're only modifying the local variables that were created when you received `game.userX` and `game.userY` as arguments. The attributes of the `game` object are not going to be changed (unless the value is something very unlikely that can update in place).

You probably need to pass the `game` object to the `move` function, so it can do the attribute updates directly. Or something like that, you've shown little enough of your code it's not entirely clear what the best design would be. For example, I might consider that making a `Player` class could make sense, which could track its own `x` and `y` coordinates. Then the `move()` function might become a method of that class.